# Convert Milliseconds to Hours, minutes and seconds

Tags: time, format, converters

Yes I know there are others who have asked the same question but their solution won't work in this case.

Here is my problem.

I'm summing a verly large number of integers. In fact so many that the SUM function won't work.

So I do this:

> Sum(cast(LotsofIntegers as decimal))  which gives me 3472201304

I want to view this in hh:mm:ss.  The problem is that the Dateadd function won't accept such a large number.  otherwise I could just do this

> CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(ms,Sum(cast(LotsofIntegers as
>   decimal)),0),114)

which is the common solution.

I'd rather not have to do this the very hard way with a whole bunch of divisions.

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (MySQL syntax; convert to your RDBMS of choice):

```
SELECT CONCAT( 
    CAST((@hours := FLOOR(SUM(msec)/3600000)) AS CHAR), 
    ":", 
    CAST((@minutes := FLOOR((SUM(msec) - @hours * 3600000) / 60000)) AS CHAR), 
    ":", 
    CAST((@seconds := FLOOR((SUM(msec) - @hours * 3600000 - @minutes * 60000) / 1000)) AS CHAR)
) FROM my_table WHERE 1;
```

On a table of 5,000,001 rows with a sum of 25,000,706,152 (under 64-bit arithmetic), I get the correct answer of `6944:38:26`.

The problem appears to be that most common RDBMS' date difference classes (including MSSQL, which you appear to be using) can only support on the order of `2^32` milliseconds' difference because of 4-byte internal representation. This is a limitation of the RDBMS in question; apparently working with more than 4 billion msec at a time was outside the envisioned use cases. So unfortunately, unless patches are released to extend the built-in functionality (or there exists an upgraded function I haven't heard of!), the long way is the way to do it.